# Using batchExecute and execute methods on a single statement object in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I came across an old piece of code which looks like below

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch(insertQuery);
stmt.addBatch(insertQuery);
stmt.addBatch(insertQuery);
stmt.addBatch(insertQuery);

//there is some data which needs to be deleted before inserting the new data. 
stmt.execute(deleteQuery);
stmt.executeBatch();
```

Here we are batching up a few query and before executing the batch this code is executing some other delete query and then executing the batch.

Is it legal to do this?

Will the above code work as expected that it will first execute the delete query and then the batch update?

Comment: I think it's "legal", but not all JDBC driver support this

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: try to use another statement for delete

Comment: @YCF_L did you even read my question. this is an old code i came across. i suspected there could be a bug in it related to its order of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-eval-spec/index.html) (version 4.3) says:

> The behavior of the methods `executeQuery`, `executeUpdate`, and
>   `execute` is implementation-defined when a `statement`’s batch is
>   non-empty.

In other words, the behaviour is not specified and depends on the driver implementation, this means it should not be relied on.

A quick (but not thorough) scan of the [pgjdbc](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc) sources seems to indicate that the PostgreSQL driver indeed allows you to first add statements to the batch, execute a single statement, and then execute the batch.

But in the code shown, I'd suggest to simply first execute the delete query, and only then populate and execute the batch. That order would be a lot simpler to read for people unfamiliar with the code.

Comment: That's correct, however I would recommend use `PreparedStatement` batches as it could be much more efficient (i.e. send SQL only once, leverage `reWriteBatchedInserts`, etc). That however would make using different SQL impossible as `PreparedStatement` is prepared for a single SQL only

Comment: @VladimirSitnikov Agreed, but given the subject of the question (interleaving batch population, single execution and batch execution), I decided only to focus on `Statement` behavior.